# Accessing CloudFront metrics from another account

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 2 AWS accounts:

1. QA account,
2. monitoring account.

First one has a CloudFront distribution. I can see its metrics in CloudWatch in the same account.
In the same CloudWatch, I have enabled cross-account cross-region data sharing with the second - monitoring account.
Unfortunately, from the CloudWatch in the monitoring account, I cannot see any CloudFront metrics. Tried in the us-east-1/N.Virginia region, where CF supposed to expose its metrics, but I cannot see them. At the end, I would like to access CloudFront metrics from the first account while being in Ohio region in the monitoring account.

Could you please guide me, how to access those CloudFront metrics from a perspective of the second account?

Thanks in advance!

Using AWS Management Console for the second account, I tried to explore all CloudWatch metrics from different regions looking for CloudFront data, including N.Virginia, but could not find anything.

Comment: Could you describe in more details how did you enable cross-account data sharing? It's quite a multi-step process and it's easy to miss a step. For example, did you establish a trust relationship between accounts and set the CloudWatchReadAccess policy?

Comment: Yes, policies were set correctly from the start. Like you can read below in my answer, _I suspect_ that order of configuration _might_ matter.

Answer (score 0):

OK, fixed. Now, while adding widgets to CW dashboard in the **monitoring account** I can see 2 drop-down boxes with *account* and *region*. When I select **QA account** and **N.Virginia** region, I can see all required CloudFront metrics to choose from.

I am not 100% sure, why it helped, but that's what I did: I have re-configured **CloudWatch**->**Settings**->**View cross-account cross-region** again, but this time selected **Custom account selector** instead of **Account Id Input**.

Initially, I first enabled viewing data from the **monitoring account** and then enabled sharing data from the **QA account**. Maybe it has to be done in the reverse order to work from the git go.

Anyway, I hope it will help someone struggling like me.